# when use hexo to deploy my blog, macbookpro's CPU usage is very high

Tags: cpu-usage, hexo

Everytime when i deploy my blog use hexo, my computer's CPU is in high usage. anyone else have face this problems? Why and how to deal with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason that the hexo causes high cpu usage is that the theme hexo config. For me, when i set the cancas false, all problems is gone.

[config_file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GPyva.png)